# Div inside scrollable div does not expend to content width

Tags: html, css

The problem is quite simple yet challenging... I have a div that is inside a scrollable div. Both have a background image with transparency. The content of the inside div goes wider than the container's width and thus make it scroll no problem but the inside div's width does not grow bigger so we loose the background...

[Here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdKrF/7/) of the following code.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width:500px;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    background:blue;
    padding-left:200px;
}
#content{
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:30px;
    background:green;
}
#content div{
    display:inline-block;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    margin-right:15px;
    background:red;
}​
```

I have tried many workaround to not depend on the inside div's width but I haven't found any better way to do what I need.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
display:inline-block;
```

and it fix it..

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/xdKrF/11/

Comment: Thank you :) Just as I was posting it after I found the solution!

Answer (score -1):

try using `background-size:cover` property

Comment: The background is working fine, it fills the div correctly. The problem is the div's width...

Comment: you can make both the #content and #content div have 
float:left

http://jsfiddle.net/xdKrF/7/